# Does it make sense to use a hash function like MD5 for keys in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, md5

A colleague of mine uses MD5 to generate keys when generating multiple elements of the same type. For instance, if he's generating links with some text inside them, he'll use the MD5 hash of that text as the key. I've been doing this recently since he says it's a good idea for generating unique keys, but I'm wondering, does it make sense? Is there any point calling MD5 when I can just use the text itself?

Comment: I don't know React enough to know the full answer, but using a cryptographic hash in a non-cryptographic context is suboptimal because cryptographic hashes are intentionally designed to be computationally expensive to run (i.e. slow). If you must use a hashing algorithm I recommend a non-crypto hash function like MurmurHash or FNV which are much faster.

Comment: You could just use an incrementing integer.

Comment: The text itself should work fine, as long as there aren't any duplicates, but duplicates will be an issue with MD5 as well.

Comment: @Dai isn't MD5 quite fast on today's systems?

Comment: @bhspencer I read this the other day: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: @bhspencer it is not a good idea to just use an incrementing number for React keys (like the counter in a for loop). In some cases it wouldn't matter, but if the array of components can change in any way (e.g. items added/removed) then just using something like the incrementing loop index as the key will cause erroneous behaviour.

Comment: In terms of OP's question, if you can GUARANTEE the text will ALWAYS be different for every link that's being rendered at the same time, then using the text is fine. Otherwise (assuming there's no other unique identifier in for each link), you could generate a hash. I don't know about the performance of MD5 but if it's slowing you down then you probably don't need something that full on. And if making a hash, you can generate it the first time something is rendered and store it, so it's not recalculated every re-render. That will save time in big lists with frequent re-rendering.